# Delphi - How I tell the system what printer to use?

Tags: delphi, printing

To print the contents of a TRichEdit I use

```
   RichEdit.Print('My Document Name');
```

Some times I need to print it on "printer1" other times I need to print it on "printer2"

**Question:**

How I tell the system what printer to use ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You set the [`Printer.PrinterIndex`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Printers_TPrinter_PrinterIndex.html). As documented, setting '-1' sets to the default printer, and the [`Printers`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Printers_TPrinter_Printers.html) property contains a list of installed printers.

Comment: +1. Add "Printers" to your uses clause and assign Printer.PrinterIndex prior to calling RichEdit.Print